# Remember toggleClass state in local storage after page refresh JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to keep the `toggleClass` value after page refresh/page load. But it is not working. I have a hierarchical table where rows are toggled when clicked. I am using `localStorage` to retain the toggle values but when page refreshed, it did not remember the previous state.

My click event is -

```
$('tr.' + 1).toggleClass('hidden'); // Class value I am getting dynamically
localStorage.setItem('hdnvalue', 'hidden');
```

In document ready -

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    if (localStorage.getItem('hdnvalue') == 'hidden') {
        alert(localStorage.getItem('hdnvalue'));
        $('tr.' + 1).toggleClass('hidden');  // I am getting class value dynamically, here 1 is the class level
    }
});
```

Update:

HTML sample -

```
<table id="tbl_test">
  <tr class="1">
    <td>Row 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="2">
    <td>Row 1.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="3">
    <td>Row 1.1.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="3">
    <td>Row 1.1.2</td>
  </tr>  
  <tr class="1">
    <td>Row 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="2">
    <td>Row 2.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="3">
    <td>Row 2.1.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="3">
    <td>Row 2.1.2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Update -
[JSfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/n3mn0wam/)

If I hide any rows and click refresh, it does not remember the toggle state. What is wrong in my code.

Thanks

Comment: do you manage to get localStorage.getItem('hdnvalue') correctly? Does this `$('tr.' + 1)` find the element as expected? Also, why `alert(localStorage.getItem('hidden'));` ? This should alert null, right?

Comment: @mkaran, yes i got the getitem value hidden, sorry its a mistake, i am correcting now

Comment: Can you please post a sample of your html?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/04ttfzL3/1/

Comment: Have you set the .hidden class in your css like this: `.hidden{
  display:none;
}`

Comment: (Else use toggle instead of toggleClass) :)

Comment: @mkaran, yes my css is display:none

Comment: Hmm your code seems to work either with toggleClass or with toggle.. https://jsfiddle.net/04ttfzL3/4/ could you please try with toggle? just in case css is not loaded properly. Else, there must be something else we cannot see here.

Comment: @mkaran, my problem I think it is getting the same table row class all the time, do you know how I can change this, because when I add alert('tr.'+lvl) - lvl is dynamic class, I am getting the same value all the time

Comment: Since I can't see how you are receiving the lvl, please take a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/04ttfzL3/8/ it may help you succeed what you are trying to do.

Comment: @mkaran, I was out from my work, please see the linked jsfiddle demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code seems working :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#tg1').click(function() {
    $("#result").html("toggled");
    localStorage.setItem('hdnvalue', 'hidden');
  });

  $('#tg2').click(function() {
    $("#result").html("not toggled");
    localStorage.setItem('hdnvalue', 'another');
  });

  if (localStorage.getItem('hdnvalue') == 'hidden') {
    $("#result").html("toggled");
    $('tr.' + 1).toggleClass('hidden');
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qj7o4zug/

Maybe the browser you are using doesnt support Storage api

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Code for localStorage/sessionStorage.
} else {
    // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
}
```

Did you get some errors in the console ?

**EDIT**

Here is the code fixed :

```
//$(document).ready(function() {
$('#reset').click(function(event) {
  $('tr').each(function(i, el) {
    localStorage['hdn_hiding' + i] = 'show';
  });
});

$('tr').click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  var m_indx = $(this).index();
  var currentLevel = parseInt($(this).attr('class')),
    state = $(this).hasClass('hiding'),
    nextEl = $(this).next(),
    nextLevel = parseInt(nextEl.attr('class'));
    debugger;
  while (currentLevel < nextLevel) {
    nextEl.toggle(state);
    nextEl = nextEl.next();
    nextLevel = parseInt(nextEl.attr('class'));
  }

  var $item = $(this).closest('tr');
  var index = m_indx;

  $item.toggleClass('hiding');
  if ($item.hasClass('hiding')) {
    localStorage.setItem('hdn_hiding' + index, 'hiding');
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem('hdn_hiding' + index, 'show');
  }

});

if (typeof(localStorage) == 'undefined') {
  alert('Your browser does not support HTML5 localStorage. Try upgrading.');
} else {
  $('tr').each(function(i, el) {
    var r = localStorage['hdn_hiding' + i] == 'hiding';
    if (r) {
      var currentLevel = parseInt($(this).attr('class')),
        nextEl = $(this).next(),
        nextLevel = parseInt(nextEl.attr('class'));
      while (currentLevel < nextLevel) {
        nextEl.hide();
        nextEl = nextEl.next();
        nextLevel = parseInt(nextEl.attr('class'));
      }      
    } 
  });
}
//});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ctuq3z1o

Comment: I am using current Chrome browser, console error is showing - 'VM1383:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeAttribute' of null'

Comment: Though I am getting the class value dynamically but when I add alert('tr.'+lvl), I am getting the same value all the time, any advice

Comment: Hi Quentin, my problem is it is getting all the time same table row value, how can I change this, because I need to keep hidden rows where class is hidden, thanks

Comment: Can you provide a little jsfiddle to show your issue ?

Comment: Hi Quentin, sorry, I was out from my work, please see the updated question and jsfiddle

Comment: Hi, ok let me some minutes to fix your problem ;)

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood but do you want something like this ? https://jsfiddle.net/ctuq3z1o/

Comment: Basically I want when I hide something and refresh page, it needs to stay same means hidden but the other open needs to remain open

Comment: I hide all rows from row 1 and refresh, its back to again all opened,. Its not keeping those rows hidden

Comment: Sorry Quentin, just I update my browser and it is working what I am looking for. Please add the code here and I will accept as an answer, many many thank for your help

Comment: Happy to help, I edited my answer. Have a great day !

Answer (score 0):

The current code implementation of localStorage usage should work:

`localStorage.setItem('hdnvalue', 'hidden');`

Refresh the page and then:

`localStorage.getItem('hdnvalue') \\hidden`

`localStorage.getItem('hdnvalue') == 'hidden'` \true